# Javascript getElementById <img>

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

i was wondering if there is a way to acess an image's onclick property by using getElementById?

e.g.

```
lastTopic = document.getElementById('topicID').src;
lastTitle = document.getElementById('topicID').title;
```

these vars are stored so i was wondering if there is a way to access the related onclick event also?

thanks.

Comment: Just a note: `click` is an event. `onclick` is a handler.

Comment: @Alin: `onclick` is an attribute, and also a property (the property reflects the attribute); what you *assign* to it is a handler.

Comment: @Alin @T.J. Crowder `onclick` is neither attribute nor handler. It is a variable which when interpreted in the context of an element object is an attribute that points to a handler.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder What you said is just like saying that if you have `var fn = function(){};`, then `fn` is not a function.

Comment: @box9: *"`onclick` is neither attribute nor..."* That's kind of going to come as a surprise to the W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#handler-onclick It says they *"...must be supported by all HTML elements, as both content attributes and IDL attributes..."* (an "IDL attribute" being what we commonly call a "reflected property": http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-dom-interfaces.html#reflecting-content-attributes-in-idl-attributes).

Comment: @Alin I didn't think I needed to point out that I wasn't being serious ;) I just found the discussion hilarious - until I saw that T.J. Crowder had a real point though -- see his answer below.

Comment: @box9: Sorry, missed that you were joking. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Did you saw on your link that `The following are the event handlers`?

Comment: @Alin: *"What you said is just like saying..."* It's just that you corrected iEisenhower incorrectly (he said "property" quite correctly). If you correct someone, the onus is on you to be correct about it! :-) Now, apparently what you said was *also* correct according to the spec's terminology (which is unfortunate, but not your fault).

Comment: @Alin: Yes, I did indeed. Interesting terminology that, and unfortunately imprecise for a spec. :-) Perfectly fine for normal conversation, of course.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - not a problem. I'm learning about the finer details of browser javascript in the mean time. Thanks :)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder *he said "property" quite correctly* I corrected him for saying onclick is an event, not for saying onclick is a property :).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Also I would like to stand by the terminology spec and point out that because you can only register one handler with the `onclick` property one may consider it correct to call the `onclick` a handler. Of course these are only minor issues. The point I was trying to make from the start was not to confuse an event with its handler.

Comment: @Alin: Fair 'nuff, and agreed re minor. (And actually, I *just now* saw the "onclick event" bit at the end of his question. I thought you were correcting the "onclick property" at the *beginning* of his question. Sorry 'bout that bit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get any DOM attribute value using element.getAttribute(attributeName) method.

As @box9 said, you need to bind onclick event dynamically or through onclick attribute in image tag.

Comment: lastClick = document.getElementById('topicID').getAttribute('onclick');
lastClass = document.getElementById('topicID').getAttribute('class'); this is the solution that solved my issue. thanks again to everyone again.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, to set the onclick property:

```
document.getElementById('topicID').onclick = function () {
   ...
};
```

Or to get it:

```
alert(document.getElementById('topicID').onclick);
```

Comment: i tried the get method but it returns null every time for some reason. i am checking to see if i am calling it wrong. the source and title works so im not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @iEisenhower - IS there an onclick value? If not it'll return `undefined`.

Comment: i will think this through and then give my response. i think all of you have given me enough clues to help me investigate this issue. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to remember what `onclick` actually is: It's an attribute (and a reflected property) that can be used to attach a handler to the `click` event using the old, "DOM0" (e.g., never-standardized) mechanism.

If you are attaching a `click` handler using a standardized mechanism like `addEventListener` or IE's near-equivalent `attachEvent`, `onclick` will remain `null` or `undefined` because those are not assigned to the `onclick` attribute or property.

Here's an exploration of this diffrence ([live example](http://jsbin.com/oliho5)):

HTML:

```
<p>This one has an onclick:
<img src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0f1f6b8a8416c6cf0a97cfc864889788?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG' id='dom0img' onclick='dom0click(this);'></p>
<p>This one has a DOM2 click handler:
<img src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG' id='dom2img'></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {

  var dom0img, dom2img;

  dom0img = document.getElementById('dom0img');
  dom2img = document.getElementById('dom2img');
  if (dom2img.addEventListener) {
    dom2img.addEventListener('click', dom2click, false);
    display("Attached DOM2-style handler to dom2img via addEventListener");
  }
  else if (dom2img.attachEvent) {
    dom2img.attachEvent('onclick', dom2click);
    display("Attached DOM2-style handler to dom2img via attachEvent");
  }
  else {
    display("Can't attach DOM2-style handler to dom2img");
  }

  display("dom0img.onclick = " + dom0img.onclick);
  display("dom2img.onclick = " + dom2img.onclick);
};

function dom0click(img) {
  display("DOM0 click on " + img.id);
}
function dom2click() {
  display("DOM2 click on " + this.id);
}
function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = msg;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}​
```

Output on Chrome:

```
Attached DOM2-style handler to dom2img via addEventListener
dom0img.onclick = function onclick(event) { dom0click(this); }
dom2img.onclick = null
```

Output on IE6 and IE8:

```
Attached DOM2-style handler to dom2img via attachEvent
dom0img.onclick = function anonymous() { dom0click(this); }
dom2img.onclick = null
```

Output on Firefox:

```
Attached DOM2-style handler to dom2img via addEventListener
dom0img.onclick = function onclick(event) { dom0click(this); }
dom2img.onclick = undefined
```

Comment: +1. You say onclick will remain `null` though. Will it be set to `null` or will it "remain" `undefined`?

Comment: @box9: It depends on the browser. (I *just* added `undefined`, because I saw that in the Firefox results.) The default value of the property seems to be `null` on most browsers.